# Can an Indian citizen get a Polish visa from Singapore?

Tags: india, singapore, poland

As far as I know, all Indian citizens (and the citizens of the Indian vassal countries) are obliged to get a Polish visa from India.

Can an Indian citizen get a Polish visa from Singapore if he is, for either education or job purposes, staying in Singapore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb observed by virtually all embassies, **if you are legally resident in a country, you can apply for visas in that country**.

For what it's worth, the [Visas page of the Embassy of Poland to Singapore](https://www.gov.pl/web/singapore/visas---general-information) states no restrictions regarding who can apply for visas there.

Comment: But if you look at the required documents for an application (https://www.gov.pl/web/singapore/c-type-schengen-visa) you will see that proof of residence in the consular district is required.